# I'm trying to set up a script for myself that adds the current working directory to my path permanently

Tags: sed

Currently have a shell script called path.sh that reads

```
cat /etc/zsh/zshenv |\
 sed "s|bashscripts|bashscripts:$PWD|g" |\
 sudo tee >> /etc/zsh/zshenv && zsh
```

my path has :/bashscripts at the end of it. The idea is to tack on $PWD to the end of $PATH. But currently I cannot get it to work the way I intend it. I intend to be able to from any user type path.sh and the current working directory be added to the end of path.
But it is not working this way so far.

I am also using zsh not bash. If that helps.

Comment: just run `path+=$PWD` if you want it for the current session...

Comment: Your sudo tee construct looks wrong. It does absolutely nothing useful!

Comment: thank you but just pointing out the errors doesn't help Marcus please provide something constructive to go along with that. Telling me my script is wrong isn't helpful, I know it is wrong that is why I'm posting here.

Comment: @don_crissti I want the changes to be permanent so that i don't have to go back to all the directories and type PATH+=$PWD but that gives me an idea  I could just do PATH+=$PWD && echo "PATH=$PATH:$PWD" >>  ~/.zshrc but so far it has not been successful in adding it to path,. it works in the terminal but not in the script, I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:'$PWD >> /etc/zshrc
source /etc/zshrc
```

should done the work, but I'm not on zsh. zshr to take effect in all shells (zshenv is only read at the start of a login shell)

Comment: it doers not work. I just tried that before checking on this again. It works perfectly in the terminal and not at all in the script.

Comment: I believe I may have found a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution posted by someone else in another thread

```
backupPATH=$PATH 
function mkpath {
    [ -d "$(pwd)/vendor/bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/vendor/bin":"$PATH"
    [ -d "$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin" ] && export PATH="$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin":"$PATH"

}
alias resetpath="PATH=$backupPATH"
```

Comment: How does this make the change to `PATH` permanent?  Also, it can be dangerous to put "untrusted" directories early in the path.  You may be better off to put them at the end.